# C++: Will structs be copied implicitly

Tags: c++, struct, copy, pass-by-reference, null-pointer

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm wondering if structs are copied in the following case:

```
struct foo {
  int i;
  std::vector<int> bar;
}

class Foobar {
  foo m_foo;

  void store(foo& f) {
    this->m_foo = f;
  }
}

void main() {
  Foobar foobar;
  {
    foo f;
    f.i = 1;
    f.bar.insert(2);
    foobar.store(f);
  }
  // will a copy of f still exist in foobar.m_foo, or am I storing a NULL-Pointer at this point?
}
```

The reason why I am asking this is that I am originally a .NET developer and in .NET structures will be copied if you pass them to a function (and classes are not).
I'm pretty sure it would be copied if store was not declared to take f by reference, but I cannot change this code.

**Edit:** Updated the code, because I didn't know that the `vector.insert` would affect my question. In my case I store the struct as a member in a class, not a vector.
So my question really was: will `f` be copied at `this->m_foo = f;`?

Comment: Note that in C++, unlike in C#, a `struct` is exactly the same as a `class` in almost every way.  the main difference is that in a struct everything is `public` by default whereas in a `class` everything is `private` by default.

Comment: @JohnDibling: That is a very good note to go together with an answer :) In C# `class` and `struct` have different behaviors, stating that in C++ they have the same behavior without clarifying which begs the question: *But, will they be copied?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: You'd have to get a pointer to a stack allocated struct and then let that struct go out of scope in order to end up with a dangling reference in your vector... but even then, you wouldn't have stored a `NULL`. C and C++ pointers are simple things, and will continue to point at a memory location long after that memory location has become invalid, if your code doesn't overwrite them.

It might also be worth noting that `std::vector` has a decent set of copy and move functions associated with it that will be called implicitly in this case, so the `bar` vector inside the struct will also be copied along with the simple integer `i`. Standard library classes tend to be quite well written, but code by other folk has no such guarantee!

Now, as regards your edit:

```
class Foobar {
  foo m_foo;

 void store(foo& f) {
    this->m_foo = f;
  }
}
```

You will *still* not have any problems with the `foo` instance stored in `m_foo`. This is because `this->m_foo = f` invokes a copying operation, as `m_foo` is not a variable of a reference or pointer type. If you had this instead: `foo& m_foo` then you would run into difficulties because instead of copying a `foo` instance you are instead copying a *reference* to a `foo` instance, and when that instance goes out of scope, the reference is no longer valid.

Comment: What does dangling references have to do with the original question? The OP wanted to know if the struct would be copied, to which the answer is yes. :-)

Comment: @MarkIngram From the OP's code block, _"// will a copy of f still exist in foos, or am I storing a NULL-Pointer at this point?"_

Comment: That's good to know. But my example was not exactly what I use in my program. Can you please answer my changed question too?

Comment: @Karsten that's quite a big change ;-) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the struct will be copied, in the following function:

`foos.insert(f);`

As a copy is made, you won't be storing a null pointer / null reference.

However, like you've said, it *won't* be copied when you call `store(f);` as the function accepts the argument as a reference.

Your edit will still make a copy of Foo. You are assigning one instance of a variable to another instance of a variable. What you *aren't* doing is assigning one pointer (reference in C#) to another. You could probably do with doing some reading around C++ object instances, pointers, and references.

Answer (score 2):

A copy of `f` is made during `foos.insert(f)`

```
void store(foo& f) {
  foos.insert(f);
}

void main() {
  {
    foo f;
    f.i = 1;
    f.bar.insert(2);
    store(f);
  }
  // at this place, local variable `f` runs out of scope, it's destroyed and cleaned up
  // foos is holding the copy of `f`
}
```

Comment: ...but that doesn't answer the question ;-)